# External link staying within website

Tags: html, hyperlink

If I have a link that is eg.: www.google.com, the link goes to mydomain.com/www.google.com.

If the http:// is at the beginning, the link goes to www.google.com.

Is there a way to ensure that the link does go to the external site, using php etc?

This link goes to mydomain.com/www.google.com:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

This link goes to www.google.com (as I want for all):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

Ended up using this to verify:

```
if(strpos($URL, "http://") !== false) $URL = $URL;
else if (strpos($URL, "https://") !== false) $URL = $URL;
else $URL = "http://$URL";
```

Comment: The way is "make sure you put http:// in front of the link", no?

Comment: Except it can't be guaranteed that it will be this way in the database.

Comment: If you wanted, you could run your files through a filter that looks for all occurrences of `<a href=` and makes sure that the next few characters are `"http://` - but then what would you do with the one "link" that you didn't want to be external...

Comment: what database are you talking about?

Comment: That could work for my application of it. Will have a think.

Comment: then you have to either scan all of your database entries and check for all TLD or you can guarantee that's its in there by doing some regular expression validation before it goes into the database

Comment: Yah, I just coded something to do it. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: `sed 's/\(\<a href=\"\)\(http:\/\/\)/\1/g' | sed 's/\(\<a href=\"\)/\<a href=\"http:\/\//g'` first takes away any http:// that you may have, and then puts it all back again...

Comment: @Andrew - Glad you figured it out. Sometimes you just have to think out loud...

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `http://` in front of the link, that's how the internet works, there are other protcolos such as `https`, `ftp` etc otherwise a link such as `<a href="google.com">` is a relative link and assumes its an internal link within your domain

Comment: You mean "internal link within your domain"... not "your page".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, then you can check the link.

Check if the link start with http://, and if it does that is ok, otherwise, prepend the link with http://.

This will make sure your link will open in external site.